# this.notifyAll(); is not working in java code

Tags: java

This is a part of my java code, in this code there are labels which are counting numbers from 0 up to so on, I want to stop labels to count when I click the button 1st time, and I want to restart the labels to count again when I click the button 2nd time, the problem is that the labels are not restarting there counting when I am clicking the button 2nd time, so please tell how should I notify all the labels to restart there counting???

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;



public class Main implements ActionListener {


    JButton button = new JButton("Click");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    boolean wait=false;


    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new Main();
    }


    public Main() {
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        new Producer().execute();
    }


    public class Producer extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
        public Void doInBackground() {
            for(int infinite=0; infinite!=-1; infinite++) {
                new Counter().execute();
                try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}     
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class Counter extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        JLabel label = new JLabel();

        public Counter() {
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            frame.add(label);
        }

        public Void doInBackground() {
            synchronized (this) {
                for(int i=0; i!=-1; i++) {
                    if(wait==true)
                        try {this.wait();} catch(Exception exp) {exp.printStackTrace();}
                    label.setText(""+i);
                    try {Thread.sleep(200);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}      
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clicked) {
        if(wait==false)
            wait=true;
        else if(wait==true) {
            synchronized (this) {
                this.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like `boolean wait=false` should be `volatile`.

Comment: If `wait` is accessed only within `synchronized` blocks (which it really should be), there is no need for it to be volatile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a place where you ever reset wait to false.  Try this and see if it gets you unstuck:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clicked) {
    if(wait==false) {
        wait=true;
    } else {
        wait=false;
        synchronized (this) {
            this.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @NotHamzAw this wasn't really meant as a solution so much as a possible starting point.  What you want to do is to make the change above, then run through your code in a debugger to see what the remaining problem(s) are.  I can recommend both IntelliJ and Eclipse as excellent free IDEs with integrated debuggers.  Start off by putting breakpoints in the actionPerformed() method, and also on the "label.setText(""+i);" line.  You might also want to temporarily set the subsequent Thread.sleep(200) to something like Thread.sleep(10000), so that last breakpoint won't drive you crazy.